# Jumping to a searched for word in a textview

Tags: search, focus

In Android Studio how do you jump to or scroll to a desired word in a large section of scrollable text in a textView? I can retrieve the index position of any given word I am searching for.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by placing multiple TextViews within my ScrollView, with each TextView having an id (obviously). Then I could jump to the view by setting it to true such as:

if (button1); textView1.setfocus(true);
else if (button2); textView2.setfocue(true);

Though specific words or such aren't jumped to, blocks of texts such as a chapter or topic could be.